# UICollectionView not recognized in collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a problem I can't solve for some hours now...

I have multiple UICollectionViews with different numbers of cells and different cellsizes. The CollectionViews are created programmatically and the delegates and datasources are set.

The collectionviews are created like this:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
collectionViewOne = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,150) collectionViewLayout:layout];
[collectionViewOne setTag:99];
[collectionViewOne setDataSource:self];
[collectionViewOne setDelegate:self];
[collectionViewOne registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[collectionViewOne setBackgroundColor:bgColor];
[collectionViewOne setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[collectionViewOne setBounces:YES];
[collectionViewOne setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:YES];
[collectionViewOne setScrollEnabled:YES];
[collectionViewOne setRestorationIdentifier:@"collectionViewOne"];
[scrollView addSubview:collectionViewOne];
```

My functions are like these:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"restorationIdentifier: %@", collectionView.restorationIdentifier);

    if (collectionView == collectionViewOne)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (collectionView == collectionViewTwo)
    {
        return 4;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"restorationIdentifier: %@", collectionView.restorationIdentifier);

    if (collectionView == collectionViewOne)
    {
        return CGSizeMake(100, 150);
    }
    else if (collectionView == collectionViewTwo)
    {
        return CGSizeMake(200, 150);
    }
    else
    {
        return CGSizeMake(200, 150);
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"restorationIdentifier: %@", collectionView.restorationIdentifier);

    if (collectionView == collectionViewOne)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; 
        [cell addSubview:imageView];
    }
    else if (collectionView == collectionViewTwo)
    {
        //create cell of type 2
    }
    return cell;
}
```

In my log I get the following output (for example):

**restorationIdentifier in numberOfItemsInSection: (null)
restorationIdentifier in sizeForItemAtIndexPath : (null)
restorationIdentifier cellForItemAtIndexPath: collectionViewOne**

collectionViewOne is the restorationIdentifier on collectionViewOne. So why is it not recognized in the first two methods?

Ofcourse the result is that I get crashes because the cellsizes and number of cells in the different CollectionViews are not properly set. The error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UICollectionViewData.m:341
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x8c31c10> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How and where do you set `collectionViewOne` and `collectionViewTwo`? And what crash are you getting exactly?

Comment: I set them in a method which I call in viewDidLoad. The crash I'm getting is like Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong without more code and the exact crash, but I don't see anything in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method that's handling the collection view not being one or two. Have you confirmed that `collectionViewOne` and `collectionViewTwo` are not nil in these methods?

Comment: I updated the question. handling collectionviews other than one and two happens in "else"

Comment: And collectionViewOne and collectionViewTwo are not nil. But "if (collectionView == collectionViewOne)" does not fire

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is solved. The problem was the fact that I used the same UICollectionViewFlowLayout for both UICollectionViews. This caused the exception.

In the end I used different classes for the two controllers, this solved the problem of selecting the right CollectionView in the delegate's methods.

Thanks all for your input!

Comment: I cannot thank you enough!!! This was driving me absolutely CrAzY!!! To summarize, this error occurs when you have more than one UICollectionView present, and you use the same UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance for both of them. Makes sense when I think about it. Each UICollectionView MUST have it's own UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tag property of the collection view to identify which collection view is which. Like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"restorationIdentifier: %@", collectionView.restorationIdentifier);

    if (collectionView.tag == collectionViewOneTag)
    {
        //create cell of type 1
    }
    else if (collectionView.tag == collectionViewTwoTag)
    {
        //create cell of type 2
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Where collectionViewOneTag and collectionViewTwoTag are integers that can be defined in code or in the xib file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but the restorationIdentifier and the Tag are both not recognized in the first two methods